# How to enable Google Hangouts in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-hangouts

How do you enable Google Hangouts in Chromium?

If I open a chat/call window in Gmail, it shows a link to "Enable Hangouts". The link takes me to [this page](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3115176?hl=en), which doesn't mention anything specific to Chromium, and all the steps listed I've already completed. It links to a plugin to install, but that's only for Internet Explorer, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: what happens if you use directly https://hangouts.google.com? Do you get the same request (to enable hangouts)?

Comment: @AntonelloPiemonte, Hangouts/Voice work just fine by themselves. It's just the link in Gmail that says Hangouts isn't enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Hangouts Chrome App: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-hangouts/knipolnnllmklapflnccelgolnpehhpl?hl=en

That should bring Hangouts to Chromium.